# Bash: How to filter a .log.gz file and export the filtered results?

Tags: bash

I have a very big log file saved as .log.gz.
All I want from this log is simply records that contained the string "px=stringABC" and export the filtered result as .log.gz. Of course, I want to do in bash environment here.

So my question can split into two parts:

1. How to filter the string "px=stringABC" from .log.gz file in bash?
   This line seems work as a filter: gunzip -c xxxx.log.gz | grep "px=stringABC"
2. How I export the filtered result and save it as .log.gz?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried this: gunzip -c xxxx.log.gz | grep "px=stringABC", but somehow it take very long to load.

Comment: Edit your question to add the above attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
zgrep px=stringABC foo.log.gz | gzip > foo-filtered.log.gz
```

`zgrep` is a wrapper for  `grep`, which supports reading `.gz` files.
The output is piped to `gzip` to recompress the filtered lines, which are then streamed to another file.

If `zgrep` is not available in your environment for whichever reason,

```
zcat foo.log.gz | grep px=stringABC | gzip > foo-filtered.log.gz
```

does approximately the same.

Comment: Thanks @AKX! 
They work! but just require a quotation mark for the string.